# How to change and get state from TouchableHighlight onPress?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, bind, state

I have a problem on how to get and set the state from function that I call on onPress. However I have no problem to get and set somewhere else. How can I change or get state from onPress?

Here is mycode:

Button:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.submit_button} underlayColor='#FCD4A9' onPress={this.saveAbsenceData}>
  <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'white'}}>
   Submit
  </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

saveAbsenceData function:

```
saveAbsenceData() {

  () => this.setState({
    visible: true
  })

  let formdata = new FormData();

  formdata.append("start_date", ()=> this.state.startDate);
}
```

with code above the state is not changing and **this.state.startDate** is empty

Answer (score 1):

this might be because you are not binding `this` on your method `saveAbsenceData`. add following code snippet in your constructor.

```
this.saveAbsenceData.bind(this)
```

or try following

```
onPress={()=> this.saveAbsenceData()}
```